# How can i set the path to library as relative path from exe file in code blocks?

Tags: mingw, codeblocks

This is probably a very stupid question but i can't find a way to specify the path to my dll files. I've set the search directory relative to the root directory of the project and it runs fine from within code blocks.

the problem is that when i double click on the exe file it can't find the libraries. I have tried to set the path relative to the exe file but it stil can't find the files.

Answer (score 0):

Before code::blocks runs/debugs your program, it sets up all the required paths for your app to run. These are defined in your *.cbp file.
If you want to "double click" your exe and expect it to find your dlls, you should do one of the following:-

1. Have your needed dlls in your exe's CWD.
2. Have your needed dlls in
   one of your search path env. vars.
3. Open a console and -> 'set PATH="**X:\Path\to your dll's\dir**";%PATH% && **myapp.exe**'
4. Make use of a [manifest file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You will want to make use of option #1 and maybe #4 if you decide to deploy your app on other machines
[HERE IS A USEFULL MSDN ARTICLE ON THE TOPIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications)